# Block websites in Debian

Tags: linux, networking, web

I am trying to block websites using /etc/hosts.

Here is my hosts file.

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       debian.localhost        debian
#The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts 

::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback 

fe00::0 ip6-localnet 

ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix 

ff02::1 ip6-allnodes 

ff02::2 ip6-allrouters

0.0.0.0 facebook.com

127.0.0.1 https://facebook.com
```

Since it is not working,Please tell me what is going wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you are trying to block facebook from the host file.Just remove other IPV6 entries from your hosts file. (to make it more readable)
try to add following

```
127.0.0.1 facebook.com   (you don't need to put http in front of the domain name)
```

NOTE : you can put any address in front of your domain. but it is easy to put 127.0.0.1.

so your computer will try to resolve facebook.com and then query the hosts file first. It will return 127.0.0.1 instead of the actual facebook ip address.

Comment: can you please paste your hosts file ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's right, but when I tried doing the same, I had to block many other addresses, since you have many domains that are linked to Facebook.

In my case, I had to add those lines :

```
127.0.0.1 www.facebook.com
127.0.0.1 facebook.com
127.0.0.1 static.ak.fbcdn.net
127.0.0.1 www.static.ak.fbcdn.net
127.0.0.1 login.facebook.com
127.0.0.1 www.login.facebook.com
127.0.0.1 fbcdn.net
127.0.0.1 www.fbcdn.net
127.0.0.1 fbcdn.com
127.0.0.1 www.fbcdn.com
127.0.0.1 static.ak.connect.facebook.com
127.0.0.1 www.static.ak.connect.facebook.com
```

And it worked perfectly well, whether on Debian, Ubuntu or Fedora. I guess that when you try to go on Facebook, you must be using a domain other that the simple "facebook.com".